# Nagios: Error: Could not open command file /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd

Tags: php, nginx, nagios

I read a lot of answers here and some googled - but can't make it work.

Nagios 4.1;
CentOS 7.0;
Nginx 1.6.3;

`nagios` group have `nginx` user:

```
# cat /etc/group | grep nagios
nagios:x:994:apache,nginx,nagios
```

Directory and file have permissions for `nagios` group:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/nagios/var/ | grep rw
...
drwxrwsr-x 2 nagios nagios    61 Jul  3 10:12 rw

# ls -l /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/
total 0
prw-rw---- 1 nagios nagios 0 Jul  3 10:24 nagios.cmd
srw-rw---- 1 nagios nagios 0 Jul  3 10:12 nagios.qh
```

PHP-FPM pool also uses `nagios` user and group:

```
# cat /etc/php-fpm.d/nagios.conf | grep -E 'user|group'
;listen.group = nagios
user = nagios
group = nagios
```

But after each restart - I still have "*Could not open command file /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd*".

Answer (score 0):

Chown for `/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/` and `/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd` hepled:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
prw-rw---- 1 nagios nginx 0 Jul  3 10:45 /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd

# ls -l /usr/local/nagios/var/
total 148
...
drwxrwsr-x 2 nginx  nginx     61 Jul  3 10:45 rw
```